# Primitive data types some questions

Tags: java, primitive-types, narrowing

I'm studying Java and I have some unclear matters I'll be very glad if anybody could help.

**First question**

the approx value of int is : 2.147.483,647

the approx value of long is : 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

[This website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says:

> "An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int"

Which mean that in case I'm not adding the letter L/l to the end of a variable name

such as :

```
long num=3515; //no letter L/l at the end
```

So variable `num` considered as `int` type not as long type.

So I made this program:

```
public class caluMaxNum
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        long max=2147483640; //doesn't have letter L/l so it consider as an int
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            max++; 
            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
2147483641
2147483642
2147483643
2147483644
2147483645
2147483646
2147483647
2147483648
2147483649
2147483650
2147483651
```

The approx value of int is : 2,147,483,647 and variable max is int, so how did it print the bold values?

**Second question:**

About narrowing conversions:

Is my statement true?

byte type (8 bits) and short type (16 bits) could be convert to char type (16 bits) only in cases the values found on byte/short type is one of the following values : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 Otherwise there will be a run-time error

**- third and last question :**

when I declare numeric variables types such as:

```
float num1=34.1;
float num2=34.1F
long num3=43
long num4=953L
```

What if the letter symbolize could I also declare variable with other types use their first letter? why should it be included what is the difference between num1 to num2 and to num3 to num4?

Comment: To answer your first question, an integer literal is the actual number, like `2147483640`. That's an integer literal. `2147483640L` is a long literal. That's what that phrase meant. You don't have to have an "L" at the end of your variable name to make it be a `long`. Defining the variable as `long num` does that. Also, when assigning to a variable, like `long num = 3515`, there is no need to have the "L" at the end of the number. It will be correctly assigned as a `long`. I hope this helps clear up your confusion a bit :)

Comment: Well I just learned something new about `long`s haha. It turns out that it actually is an `int` until the "L" is put at the end, though once it's assigned to a `long` variable then it is a `long`. So for integer literals bigger than the maximum value for `int`s (2147483647), you actually do have to have the "L" at the end. My apologies for missing that point in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. While the value used to initialize max may be an int, max is explicitly declared as a long, perfectly consistent w/ your output.
2. The answer depends on what you mean by "convert".
3. num1 & num2 are the same; num3 and num4 are completely different values, regardless of what (if any) suffix is used.

Comment: The literals used for `num1` and `num2` are not the same. For one, the `num1` assignment doesn't compile. And I think you missed the point of `num3` and `num4`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help
1.
I wrote a program :

public class Hello
{<br/>
public static void main(String [] args)
     {      
long y = 2147483671;
System.out.println(y);
       }
}

Is says "integer number too large" why?

2. by convert I mean to put the variable's value of data type byte/short into an variable's value of char type 

3. I still don't understand for what use are the letters in the end of the number.

Comment: @JaVaPG: 1. 2147483671 IS too large for an int (you left off the L, remember?), but isn't too large to fit in y.

Comment: @JaVaPG: 3.  The letter serves the same purpose for a value as the type declaration does for a variable.

Comment: @JaVaPG: 2. Replacing "convert" with "put" doesn't help.  Maybe some examples are in order.